Create a key using an @attribute, but scaning by this @attributes starting letters
I am using XSLT 1.0
I transform the following xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test_1.xsl"?>
 <Features>
  <Feature item="a1" area="1"></Feature>
  <Feature item="a1" area="1"></Feature>
  <Feature item="a2" area="1"></Feature>
  <Feature item="a2" area="1"></Feature>
  <Feature item="b1" area="1"></Feature>
  <Feature item="b1" area="1"></Feature>
  <Feature item="b2" area="1"></Feature>
 </Features>

via this xsl file:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">     
<xsl:key name="KeyStyle" match="Feature" use="@style"/>
<xsl:key name="KeyItem" match="Feature" use="@item"/>
 <xsl:template match="Features">
  <html>
    <xsl:for-each select="Feature[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyStyle',@style)[1])]">   
    <xsl:sort select="@style" order="ascending"/> 
     Table for style (<xsl:value-of select="@style"/>)
     <xsl:for-each select="key('KeyStyle',@style)">
     <xsl:sort select="@item" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[@item = current()/@item])">
       <p>Style=<xsl:value-of select="@style"/></p>  
       <p>Item=<xsl:value-of select="@item"/></p>  
       <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (<xsl:value-of select="@item"/>)=<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyItem',@item)/@area)"/></p> 
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each> ----------
      <br/><br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Getting this output:
<html> 
 Table for style (a)
  <p>Item=a1</p>
  <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (a1)=4</p>
  <p>Item=a2</p>
  <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (a2)=4</p>
  -----------------
 Table for style (b)
  <p>Item=b1</p>
  <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (b1)=3</p>
  <p>Item=b2</p>
  <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (b2)=3</p>
</html>

Since substring(@item, 1, 1) statement scans all (a) items ignoring what follows after (a), I apparently get the sum of all items starting with (a) :
TotalAreaOf_Items (a1)=4 and TotalAreaOf_Items (a2)=4
instead of the desired :
TotalAreaOf_Items (a1)=2 and TotalAreaOf_Items (a2)=2
I try to handle the <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyItem'... with a separate key, but the two prevailing nested xsl:for-each statements have already assigned which way the scanning is performed.
Any help will be valuable.

Instead of @style use substring(@item, 1, 1), in both the xsl:key definition and the calls to the key() function.

P.S. I see you have asked 13 questions, but did not accept a single answer. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

I had to add an extra key:
<xsl:key name="KeyItem1" match="Feature" use="@item"/>

and get sum through:
<p>TotalAreaOf_Items (<xsl:value-of select="@item"/>)=<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyItem1',@item)/@area)"/></p>

The final xsl file:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">     
<xsl:key name="KeyItem" match="Feature" use="substring(@item, 1, 1)"/>
<xsl:key name="KeyItem1" match="Feature" use="@item"/>
 <xsl:template match="Features">
  <html>
    <xsl:for-each select="Feature[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyItem',substring(@item, 1, 1))[1])]">   
    <xsl:sort select="@item" order="ascending"/> 
     Table for style (<xsl:value-of select="substring(@item, 1, 1)"/>)
     <xsl:for-each select="key('KeyItem',substring(@item, 1, 1))">
     <xsl:sort select="@item" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[@item = current()/@item])">    
       <p>Item=<xsl:value-of select="@item"/></p>  
       <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (<xsl:value-of select="@item"/>)=<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyItem1',@item)/@area)"/></p> 
     </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each> -----------------
     <br/><br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

The desired output (sums of @area of all nodes with the same @item)
<html> 
 Table for style (a)
  <p>Item=a1</p>
  <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (a1)=2</p>
  <p>Item=a2</p>
  <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (a2)=2</p>
  -----------------
 Table for style (b)
  <p>Item=b1</p>
  <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (b1)=2</p>
  <p>Item=b2</p>
  <p>TotalAreaOf_Items (b2)=1</p>
</html>

